# What is the proper syntax for an contain attribute translate

Tags: selenium, xpath

I received a xpath similar to the line below. since there is no other exemple of such a xpath availlable I'm asking out if someone has the proper syntax for it as the current one does not work in selenium, constantly yielding the 'false' result when using storeElementPresent. I suspect something might be wrong in the second translate part.

```
//a[contains(translate(@title, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), "(translate('String', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath function `contains(`*a*`,`*b*`)` returns true iff *b* is contained in *a*.

Your *a* is

```
translate(@title, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

which is the lower-case value of the `@title` attribute.

Your *b* is

```
"(translate('String', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"
```

which is a literal string containing characters `(`,`t`,`r`,`a`,`n`... – not likely what you want.

Instead, *b* should be something like `"asdf"` in order to test if the attribute value of `@title`, converted to lowercase, contains a `"asdf"` substring.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer helped find the solution in the form of

```
//a[contains(translate(@title, "ABC", "abc"), translate("string","ABC","abc"))]
```

Apparently the translate was stuck between cotes and parenthesis when it should have not.

Comment: You realize, then, that `translate("string","ABC","abc")` evaluates to just `"string"`, right?

Comment: Well what I wrote seems to work as it will yield true however way I modify the string. I'm not sure what you meant by that, this entire xpath was made to evaluate the so called specific string. Thanks for the warning however this might cue my teamate to something if there is an issue.